# Perl script behavior while exiting with 256

Tags: perl

My perl script temp.pl looks like:

```
exit 256;
```

If i do following:

```
perl temp.pl
echo $?
```

Answer is 0.

If i change, perl script to

```
exit 255;
```

And do again then, answer is 255.

is there anything wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the exit return codes are limited to single byte - 0 to 255.

The full exit code consists of the exit code itself and flags which say how the program exited - whether regularly or because of some signal (being killed, interrupted, temporarily stopped etc.).

So the value to `exit()` function is always masked with `0xff` in order to not conflict with signal delivery.

Comment: This post is pretty much entirely wrong. 1) Exit codes are not limited to one byte in general, only on his system. 2) the information in the full exit code consists of: whether the program ended successfully, the exit code passed to `exit`, the signal that terminated it, and whether a core dump was produced. 3) The signal number and core dump flag is in the lower bits, so a larger exit code would not conflict with reporting of the signal that killed the process. 4) Exit codes have nothing to do with signal delivery. 5) The value of exit is NOT always masked with `0xff`, only on some systems.

Comment: @ikegami : well, I talked about most of the unix implementations. it's of course platform specific. Regarding signal delivery - I meant to the parent process, note it's not limited to exit only, but also temporary conditions like stopped, tty blocked etc.

Comment: Re "*I talked about most of the unix implementations*", You said "*always*." not "*for some unix implementations*". That is wrong. /// Re "*note it's not limited to exit only*", Yes, it is. When a process becomes blocked, it does not set its parent shell's `$?`. Only when it exits (normally, or when killed by a signal). It's not called the exit status for nothing.

Comment: @ikegami : Please read the context. The delivery of stopped notification uses exactly the same mechanism and set of functions in the client as notification about exit.

Comment: @ikegami : check WIFSTOPPED for example.

Comment: No idea what you're going on about, but it doesn't appear to have to do with the question or answer. [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104902/ikegami-kvr000)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (and most unix systems), the status passed to `exit` is limited to 8 bits (0 to 255).

> `void exit(int status);`
>
> The `exit()` function causes normal process termination and the value of `status & 0377` is returned to the parent (see `wait`(2)).

The reason it's limited to 8 bits is to support systems with 16-bit `int`. In an `int`, `wait` must convey the following information:

- Whether the process existed normally (e.g. via `exit`).
- If it exited normally,

  - The status passed to `exit`.
- If it was terminated by a signal,

  - The number of the signal that killed the process.
  - Whether a core dump was produced.

On Windows, the status passed to `exit` is limited to 16-bits (0 to 65535).